# Performance Testing vs Profiling

Tags: java, jsp, profiling, performance-testing, jprofiler

Am working with lots of mid-complexity Java/Jsp applications and wondering what would be an added advantage of doing performance testing using say Jmeter over profiling using Jprofiler/Netbeans profiler. Would highly appreciate if anyone provides any recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Profiling and Performance Testing are different things altogether.

Performance testing happens at the system level, under varying types of load, and makes sure your system lives up to its SLAs (service level agreements).

Profiling is what you do when your performance testing shows a problem.  It helps you identify those parts of your system that contribute the most to the performance problem and shows you where to concentrate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question in response to the answer. Performance test might surface how much headroom you have... but wouldn't you want to be more pro-active in surfacing the constraints of the system (versus waiting for problems to profile)? Granted that the system evolves and the constraints may also... but if you are generally playing to the architecture, isn't there benefit in surfacing how to tune and where future problems may exist? (To see when things are starting to get balled up and maybe adjust with the levers available)